# Can you suggest a more pythonic way to find and return an element of a list that has a specific attribute value

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list of AssetClass objects where

```
class AssetClass(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
```

The list is in an arbitrary order. I'd like to find the element in the list that has a specific id (that is, where ac.id == asset_class_id).

My non-pythonic code (which works) is:

```
asset_class_list = AssetClass.query.order_by(AssetClass.title.asc())
for ac in asset_class_list:
    if ac.id == asset_class_id:
        # do stuff with ac
```

Comment: There is nothing non-pythonic about your code.

Comment: if your code works, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing non-pythonic on your code, it seems to work well..
Anyway, You can use generator with next:

```
asset_class_list = AssetClass.query.order_by(AssetClass.title.asc())
item = next( ac for ac in asset_class_list  if ac.id == asset_class_id)
```

This is more pythonic way and also it is more efficient because the generator will iterate only until it will find the the item you are looking for...
Note by @juanpa.arrivillaga: of course the efficiency can be equal when using `break` statements, but it seems more clean just like this..

Comment: This is not more efficient, if `#do stuff` simply `break`s out of the loop. And I would hardly call it more Pythonic. There is nothing not Pythonic about using a for-loop.

Comment: When you want to find an item.. for loop is a nice way, but it wont result in an assignment into variable.. thats why in my opinion it is more pythonic.. i didnt say for-loop isnt.. it is more cleaner b casue 1. Its a one liner, 2. It saves you from doing all this break and assignment inside and outside loop .

Comment: Of course it will result in an assignment to a variable. The variable is `ac` in the OP's code. They even put the comment `# do stuff with ac`. The OP's code is *perfectly pythonic the way it is*

Comment: No, I think it is *much less* clean to use `next( <gen expression> )`

Comment: Thanks for the interesting discussion. It now has me wondering what "pythonic" actually means!